# html fluorescent / metallic colors, blue, green, brown, purple, etc

Tags: html, css, graphics

I am looking to specify my text and div colors using very bright metallic or fluorescent colors.   I haven't located any standard that shows these.  Do these exist in a color specification, or can you refer me to any close attempt.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_crayola.asp) a good list of fluorescent and metallic color hex codes.